# Trying to position an element to window left and right regardless of parent container jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element a few layers deep and want to make it's parent container a few levels up so i can place elements to the edge of the window.

In the example [here](https://codepen.io/fernandob/pen/RLMZpY) i have an img inside a container with position relative, but i want it to listen or pay attention to a container a few levels up.

Any help would be awesome.

```
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  height: 50vh;
}

section.two {
  width: 90vw;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 40vh;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  padding: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make the img sit within the '.container' rather than the 'section.two', try removing the 'position: relative;' from the 'section.two'

The 'position: relative' is what the 'position: absolute' looks for e.g:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}

.container {
width: 100vw;
position: relative;
background: blue;
height: 50vh;
}

section.two {
width: 90vw;
background: red;
height: 40vh;
}

img{
position: absolute;
right: 0%;
padding: inherit;
}
```

Comment: thats the thing, i can't, i want the img to ignore its parent container(section.two) and only "listen or w/e" to .container

Comment: If you remove 'position: relative' from 'section.two' the img should listen to the '.container' div instead. Position absolute will look for the next 'position: relative' on a parent div (which will only be on the .container div once the other one is removed).

Comment: ok Laura thanks but I know that, please look at the title of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're wanting to achieve. If you want the element to completely ignore any parent elements then change it's position from absolute to fixed